# Boolean set to true when program starts without me telling it to

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings

Right, so I wanted to add a "save settings" feature to my program. I'm gonna go through all the steps of the whole saving/loading process I have setup right now. So logically, save all the settings depending on `bool saveStateToggle` when exiting the program:

```
private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(saveStateToggle == false)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                saveSettings();
                Application.Exit();
                
            }
        }
```

saveSettings is simply this:

```
private void saveSettings()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.onTopToggle = onTopToggle;
            Properties.Settings.Default.saveStateToggle = saveStateToggle;
            Properties.Settings.Default.debugToggle = debugToggle;
            Properties.Settings.Default.min = minTrackbar.Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.max = maxTrackbar.Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Then, when the program launches, in `private void Form1_Load` depending on the previously saved setting:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Properties.Settings.Default.saveStateToggle == true)
            {
                loadSettings();
            }
            else
            {
                loadDefaultSettings();
            }
        }
```

*`loadSettings();` is the same thing as `saveSettings();` but mirrored. So if `saveSettings();` is `Properties.Settings.Default.saveStateToggle = saveStateToggle;`, `loadSettings()` will have it like this: `saveStateToggle = Properties.Settings.Default.saveStateToggle;`*

Upon further debugging, I found that `saveStateToggle` is indeed `false` before `Application.Exit();`, but it mysteriously turns `true` before I even call `loadSettings();` in `private void Form1_Load` when I start the program again.

I'm at a total loss. I've checked everything and to me, everything seems logical. Could `saveStateToggle` be turning true because I'm in "Debug" configuration when running the program? Is it even possible to have a toggleable button to enable saving?

Button that toggles `saveStateToggle` true or false:

```
private void SaveStateToggleBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (saveStateToggle == false)
            {
                saveStateToggle = true;
                SaveStateToggleBtn.Text = "SAVESTATE: ON";
            }
            else
            {
                saveStateToggle = false;
                SaveStateToggleBtn.Text = "SAVESTATE: OFF";
            }
        }
```

The boolean is defined here:

```
        bool saveStateToggle = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: What's in the settings file before relaunching?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidelines on posting code. I.e. `bool saveStateToggle = true;` definition of the property is not shown making it hard to provide answer.

Comment: @Adam it should be everything from the last time the program saved to the settings file EXCEPT `saveToggleState` which should be false.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I guess I should've included that. Anyways, the boolean is defined above `public Form1(){InitializeComponent();}` which is above Form1_Load

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints on all lines that modify `saveToggleState` (there shouldn't be very many)?  Is there perhaps a series of events that unintentionally trigger the button click event for the SaveState button, say during Form_Load?  `saveToggleState` can't mysteriously turn true; something will be setting it to that.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I made MessageBox show me the state of the boolean each time after it got changed. I got no idea what's turning it true. The last MessageBox right before `Application.Exit();` shows me that it is indeed `false`. But sometimes it's good to think from the user's perspective and not over-engineer things. I realized that pretty much noone would use it.

Comment: Why not use the debugger to step through the code? Then you can see the state of the class members throughout program execution.

Comment: The most obvious bug in this code is that the bool gets saved to and loaded from the setting, but loading it does not update the button text.  So you'd think it wasn't set, but it actually was.

Comment: @HansPassant I've simplified the code for this post. There's also a `setValues();` that updates all the buttons and what not according to the booleans.

Answer (score 0):

I think **loadsettings** is changing the value.
change **saveStateToggle** to a property and put a breakpoint on the setter to see call stack and where it is being called from.

```
private bool _saveStateToggle = false;
public bool SaveStateToggle
{
    get  { return _saveStateToggle;}
    set{ _saveStateToggle = value }
}
```